# Вывести сведения о товарах, проданных продавцом, и определить товар с максимальной стоимостью

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите пожалуйста с программой

Задача: **Определить количество товаров, проданных продавцом “Иванов”, вывести сведения о них и определить товар с максимальной стоимостью.**

**Поля записи:** Продавец, Наименование, Количество, Цена, Дата продажи
Задача: Определить количество товаров, проданных продавцом “Иванов”, вывести сведения о них и определить товар с максимальной стоимостью.

*P.S. Знаю, что нужно свой код еще вставлять*

Comment: Так если вы знаете, то на что рассчитываете?) Вы даже не удосужись написать про источник данных и т.д.

Comment: ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ["Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Псевдокод:

- переменная `max_price = -1`
- переменная `количество_товаров_проданных_Ивановым = 0`
- переменная `самый_дорогой_товар = ''`
- проходим циклом по всем записям с товарами

  - если `Продавец == 'Иванов'`, то:

    - выводим сведения о товаре
    - увеличиваем счетчик `количество_товаров_проданных_Ивановым` на единицу
    - если `Цена` больше `max_price`, то

      - `max_price = Цена`
      - `самый_дорогой_товар = Наименование`

---

PS вычислительная сложность алгоритма - `O(n)`.

PSPS Т.к. в вопросе отутствует пример данных и собственного кода, исходим из того, что автору вопроса нужна помощь с алгоритмом, а не с кодом.